# Sending a gratuitous ARP on an interval - Cisco

Tags: switch, switching, mac-address, broadcast

In response to my question [Propagating Static MAC Addresses](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69294/propagating-static-mac-addresses/69300#69300) , I realize I can not avoid the unknown unicast problem.  Essentially I have hosts that forward their traffic via an L2 frame to a destination MAC.  Given there is no IP there is no ARPs and no way for the switches in the middle to 'learn' the MAC.

I was thinking I could have a Cisco switch with an SVI send gratuitous ARPs that flood the network and 'teach' all switches in the middle.  I would need the gratuitous ARPs sent out on a regular interval, greater than the expiry timeout of any middle switch.  I would then port mirror off that SVI.  That way these raw frames are no longer destined to an unknown unicast destination and flooded.

Any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why is flooding the unknown unicast frames a problem? That happens on networks all the time. If it is just the hosts and server for this application on the VLAN, then I really do not see the problem. If there are other hosts on the same VLAN, then the SVI idea is a bad idea because you can end up sending frames from the other hosts to the server, too.

Comment: Because this is essentially port mirrored traffic.  If 1G ingress is coming into Host1 it will forward 1G egress to the special MAC address.  I don't want 1G of traffic flooded to all other hosts due to the unknown unicast issue.

Comment: @RonMaupin The above will be further multiplied by the number of hosts that have this mirroring requirement.

Comment: "_If 1G ingress is coming into Host1 it will forward 1G egress to the special MAC address._" No, a host receiving a frame that is not destined to its MAC address simply drops the frame. That happens in the NIC.

Comment: @RonMaupin The hosts are running software that essentially monitors it's ingress traffic and shoots a copy of it to a defined MAC address.  If this special MAC is unknown unicast to the upstream switches it will flood these frames out all ports.  That means 1G of ingress to host1, once the mirrored traffic is shot out, will have 1G of frames shot out to all ports on the switch due to the UU problem.  Multiply this by a few hosts and links that were never intended for this traffic will be saturated.

Comment: The NIC, seeing a frame not destined to its MAC address, drops the frame before it can be sent into the network stack. The frame does not enter the host to be repeated. Based on what you say the hosts do, your SVI gratuitous ARP frame would be repeated in the manner you do not want.

Comment: @RonMaupin I understand the NICs of the non-intended hosts will drop the frames but that still doesn't alleviate the fact that the frame got there in the first place and is saturating the link.  1 Gbps of useless frames is still 1 Gbps saturating the lines of these hosts.  I have done this with static MACs it's just unmanagable IMO.  The issue is highlighted here https://imgur.com/a/Cf8Cnn4 By the way I really appreciate you taking the time to work through this.

Comment: @RonMaupin The plan with the gratuitous ARPs as to move the "AA:AC" in the image above to an SVI that gratuitous ARPs frequently.  That way all switches learn of "AA:AC" and avoid the above scenario

Comment: Well, your plan with the SVI will send ARP, which is a broadcast that _will_ get into _every_ host in the broadcast domain to be repeated to the server. In any case, Cisco switch OSes do not work that way.

Comment: @RonMaupin - Yes that's why I was wondering if Cisco can do a gratuitous ARP on an interval.  If I do a regular ARP I'd have to have hosts on every switch constantly pinging the SVI to ensure ARP traffic is generated (ARP request is broadcast, reply is unicast) if I want to ensure that no switches in the middle see the 'mirror dst' host as unknown unicast.

Comment: A gratuitous ARP is also broadcast, and the hosts, repeating everything to the server, will all send it to the server, just like an ARP request. In any case, you cannot simply create a program on the switch to do that.

Comment: @RonMaupin Looks like switches are chatty enough with their BPDUs and such to propagate their MAC all around.  I can set this special MAC to an SVI then mirror from that.

Comment: BPDUs do not work that way. They are link-only datagrams that are not propagated beyond the next link. The will only have the source interface MAC address, adn they will not be from an SVI.

Comment: @RonMaupin Makes sense.  Something is propagating the SVIs MAC out.  None of the hosts on the network are talking to it nor have it as a DG yet switches around my network, even those not directly connected, have learned about it somehow

Comment: It is probably sending out an ARP for the configured gateway.

Comment: Did you ever consider RSPAN for this?  You wouldn't even need a software on the host anymore that copies and forwards ingress traffic to another host. Rspan-monitor the monitored hosts' switch ports (rx, tx or rx/tx, as needed). RSPAN will copy the hosts' frames into/through the RSPAN VLAN. At the monitoring server's switch, configure an an RSPAN destination port and attach that special IP-less NIC to it. Put that NIC into promiscuous mode and start capturing.

Comment: This type of situation is often addressed with hard-coding the MAC address to a specific port, thus bypassing the need for source-based learning (this used to be a common requirement for certain firewall and app clustering tools).  Another approach is MAC redirects, which can pre-program the switch's TCAM to forward some/all/none of a given traffic stream as desired.  In both cases these are very much hardware/vendor dependent functions, though.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As we explained in your original question, the node to which this traffic should be flowing **MUST** send a frame for the connected switch to learn its location. And it must be a broadcast frame if you want the entire network to learn it. For IPv4, ARP takes care of this; IPv6 NDP. A gratuitous arp from a switch will only get the traffic to that switch, but not necessarily the correct port.

While, yes, flooding does naturally occur in switched networks ("fabrics"), it's a rare event that doesn't last for more than a few frames. The ARP process will usually fill the switch tables, and re-verification will keep it filled. If you doubt how little traffic is actually flooding, go to any node on any switch in your network -- preferably one in a VLAN with many other nodes -- and start a promiscuous tcpdump filtering out the local MAC and all broadcast traffic. There will be very little "foreign" traffic showing up.

This kind of unicast flooding is Very Bad(tm). It is effectively a broadcast storm, but because it's not actually broadcast traffic, the switches cannot detect and block it like a real broadcast storm. If it's only 10pps, then it's much less of a catastrophe. But when it's a significant amount of traffic, it becomes a huge problem because *every port in the entire network (carrying that VLAN) will have to carry the traffic.* Yes, your NIC will filter it out, but it still consumed bandwidth crossing the link. (your NIC received it, but didn't pass it on to you.) Do you want every node in the network eating 800mbps of traffic it doesn't want?